# Importing Quandl is giving ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, anaconda, quandl

I am working on Anaconda. 'import Quandl' is giving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'. When I try 'conda install -c anaconda quandl' in command prompt it gives 'Unable to create process using C:\Users....python.exe' 
Then I downloaded quandl from GitHub. Then I tried 'pip install quandl' in command prompt. However, again same message appeared.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do?

Of cource the documentation if for weak cowards, but why not look at https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python#retrieving-data

(Spolier: it is `import quandl`, lowercase)